# Add custom class to md-dialog-container

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

I have a button that opens a `md-dialog-container`. Is it possible to add a custom class to the root of that `md-dialog-container`?

```
<button class="button bluebutton right" ng-click="vm.launchContactActivityPopup()" ng-if="vm.isPersisted()" ng-disabled="!vm.isAllowedToRegisterContactActivity()">Contactd vastleggen</button>
```

```js
public launchContactActivityPopup(): void {
  this.$mdDialog.show({
    template: `<register-contact-activity-popup></register-contact-activity-popup>`,
    targetEvent: null,
    clickOutsideToClose: false
  });
}
```

Comment: `<register-contact-activity-popup class="your-class"></register-contact-activity-popup>`?

Comment: @AdityaParab I need to add the class to the material dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it like this.

```
<md-dialog class="myClass">
    <register-contact-activity-popup></register-contact-activity-popup>
</md-dialog>`,>`,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `panelClass`:

```
public launchContactActivityPopup(): void {
    this.$mdDialog.show({
        template: `<register-contact-activity-popup></register-contact-activity-popup>`,
        targetEvent: null,
        clickOutsideToClose: false,
        panelClass: 'myClass'
    });
}
```

Comment: I've come across that in my search but it doesn't work. Isn't panelClass for material design 2? I'm using AngularJS and Material Design.

Comment: Worked with "@angular/material": "^9.0.1" version, Thanks!